# RoR How to catch general error in parent class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
class ParentClass
  def run
  rescue StandardError => e
    p 'catch in parent class'
  end
end

class ChildClass < ParentClass
  def run
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    p 'catch in child class'
  end
end
```

Kindly review above code, I have a series of children classes.

```
instance = ChildClass.new
instance.run
```

when instance run and meet `ArgumentError`, ChildClass will handle it. If not, since the parent class will catch all general `StandardError`, any error not caught in ChildClass, will be caught in parent class eventually.

How to implement the above logic?

Comment: You need to call `super` in the child class to call the `run` method in the parent.